# I want take uri from selected file

Tags: android

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
>             intent.setType("*/*");
>             intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
>
>             try {
>                 startActivityForResult(
>                         Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Copy"),
>                         FILE_SELECT_CODE);
>             } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
>                 Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
>                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>             }
>         }
> ```

this code lead me to select file and i  want take uri of selected file,

Answer (score 3):

Hi once you get your image you need to trigger and retrieve image data using onActivityResult like this, have a dedicated result code for this operation. rough example below to give u idea

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
 Uri uri = data.getData(); // ur raw file data convert to anything u want 
 try {
 //for images
  Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
  imageView.set(bitmap) //example , you can choose what you want to with bitmap

  //for files
  InputStream inputStream;
            File file = null;
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(your URI));
                file = new File(String.valueOf(inputStream));
            }catch (Exception e){
                
            }

   }catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```